# How to connect Django with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: python, django, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I want to connect Django with Azure Cosmos DB. Either with Core SQL Or Gremlin. Do we have any existing libraries we can use to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The official Django documentation does not list anything for Cosmos DB, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/).

On Github there is an approach on creating a backend for Cosmos, but it looks like in early stage and unclear if it is continued: https://github.com/tonybaloney/django-cosmos

If you could image using the Cosmos Mongo, maybe the [Mongo Mapper for Django](https://www.djongomapper.com/) will help and [this repo, which offers a workaround to get Cosmos Mongo and the mapper working](https://github.com/skarri-microsoft/CosmosDB_Mongo_Django_Workaround).

I haven't tried any of that approaches myself, but are curios about a solution as well.